# What is the downside of putting your entire website inside an iframe of the main landing page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, iframe, frameset

I have a facebook like chat bar at the bottom of my website and I also have a few other javascriptand ajax related code that loads on page load, I have not yet fully ajaxified this website but have to put it into production the problem is that these scripts take too long each time the page refreshes, just to initialize. So I though of taking them out and putting the entire website inside an iframe or frameset and this code on the outside of the frame.

I remember back in the day in the SO community, people always told to stay away from framesets and also even iframes would get a lot of comments. Can somebody enlighten me? What should I do?

I am using alot of html5 features like webstorage and alot of css3 if that makes any diffrence.
Thanks for any insight!

Comment: I humbly recommend optimizing your JavaScript and keep your hands off iframes and frames. E.g. use only one large script instead of several small ones. Use a JavaScript framework like jQuery: The library is cached in most browsers, since many big websites use it. There are applications for iframes, but this is not one of them. Frames ... my grandma used them I believe ;-)

Comment: If it takes too long figure out WHY it takes too long.

Comment: @epascarello I think there is a memory leak or something. How can I figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean what *are* the downsides?

1. Too many requests
2. Will take a long time for the whole page to load
3. No Search Engine Optimization

Go for the ajaxified website instead. Might take you some time and effort to get started but it will be worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

In general, expect that Google won't find your content.  This will make it a lot more difficult for you to build an audience or for people who are looking for you to find you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered having the javascript not run till after the load event has fired?  If the script download time is a problem you can even have it wait till the load event to be downloaded.   As to the question about frames,  the biggest downside is from inside the frame you can't easily communicate to the browser window (you can work out some polling protocol from the window to the frame but it isn't easy).  Are you using any js library to help you?

Comment: not really, I have jQuery, I was thinking of adding modernizer but no other library

Comment: It shouldn't be difficult with jQuery to have your time consuming js run after the page loads.

Comment: yes it is already running after page load but even then specially in IE it freezes the browser for a few seconds each time it is initialized. Which is worse than page load because the user is already interacting with the page.

Comment: Can you break it up into small sections and at the end of each section schedule the next section on a timer?  This will let the event loop run and own't freeze the browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your content to be indexed by search engines like Google, don't use iframes. Google ignores those. Both, frames and iframes are more difficult or rigid to handle than e.g.  containers, in particular with JavaScript. About frames: Google will index it, but it will handle each frame as separate content, which in a downside concerning SEO.  (as far as I know).

Answer (score 1):

Googlebot ignores iframes, though occasionally a misconfigured bot may see it. Ninety-nine percent of the time the iframe will be totally ignored. This goes for Yahoo as well.

Iframes are executed at the client side, and Google simply does not execute them.